# Scala generic self type mismatch

Tags: scala, generics, self-type

I am trying to use Scala's cake pattern with generic interceptors with multiple groups (layers) of those. When end of one layer needs another layer I try to express that using self type. But it fails with Illegal inheritance. The general context of the task is I have a document model on which I am trying to do chain of validations. Toy example follows with each layer represented by just one trait.

```
trait Element
trait Leaf extends Element
trait Composed extends Element

trait Validator [A] {def validate (element : A) : String}

//second layer
trait LeafValidator extends Validator[Leaf]{
  override def validate (element : Leaf) : String = "leaf"}

//first layer
trait ElementValidator extends Validator[Element]{
  self : Validator[Leaf] =>

  override def validate (element : Element) : String = element match {
    case leaf : Leaf => super.validate(leaf)
    case _ => "other"
  }
}

case class Concrete extends LeafValidator with ElementValidator
```

The error is on the instantiation line

> illegal inheritance;  self-type apltauer.david.util.Concrete does not conform to apltauer.david.util.ElementValidator's selftype apltauer.david.util.ElementValidator with apltauer.david.util.Validator[apltauer.david.util.Leaf]    Main.scala  /Dependency/src/apltauer/david/util line 56 Scala Problem

Contravariance supresses the error but does not solve the problem as the self type is useless then.

Comment: This is not a cake pattern, your just using self-type annotation. I would recommend using composition here instead.

Comment: It will be cake pattern as soon as I expand those layers into multiple traits. Maybe the information about the cake pattern is not so important actually. I appreciate different design proposals but I would still like to resolve the mystery.

Comment: A given class can not implements a (non-variant) interface parameterized with two different type: Foo can not extend Bar[A] and Bar[B] at the same time.

Comment: But Foo can include two different Bar, Foo { val barA: Bar[A]; val barB: Bar[B] } <-- this is composition

Comment: I am not sure what the actual question is.

Comment: So you see no way of implementing this via mixins? Not even using contravariance? @AloisCochard Well the question is how achieve the sketched behaviour.

Comment: So that the call validate(obj : Element) will execute first layer which will in turn call the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The use of two variants of features breaks the (otherwise, nice and useful) cake pattern.

So I developed an enhancement, which, concerning my problem, allowed me to keep the cake pattern intact, and which I call the **Feature Pattern**. In your case:

```
trait element_validator extends validator[Element] {
   final override val element_validator = this
}
trait feature_element_validator { val element_validator : element_validator }

/* Analogous for “Leaf” */

trait validator[element_type] {
   final override val validator = this
   /* Feature code here: */
   def validate(element: element_type) = /* … */
}
trait feature_validator[element_type] { val validator : validator[element_type] }
```

So now one could say:

```
object component
   extends element_validator
   with leaf_validator
   with other_cake_feature_1
   with other_cake_feature_2
   with other_cake_feature_3
   /* etc. */
```

Inside component one would distinguish the two kinds of validator:

```
element_validator.validate(…)
leaf_validator.validate(…)
```

If only one requires, then import (which has the same effect as using the self-type-annotation for availability of names):

```
import element_validator._
validate(…)
```

I know, it is quite some boilerplate. I didn't, however, see any other solution for that than to combine cake with composition (whenever composition would be necessary).